# Disable invitation email when creating user

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I don't know how to disable sending email invitation when i create or import user.

I tried to override auth_signup module with this code but i have a recursion error: Unknown error during import: : maximum recursion depth exceeded at row 2

And the code :

```
class res_users(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        user = super(res_users, self).with_context(no_reset_password=True).create(vals)

        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with_context` will cause a recursion error when applied with `super`. `super` calls the base class, which is not what you need. What you need is to update the context of the current **instance** of the class, which is `self`.

Therefore this should work:

```
class res_users(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        user = super(res_users, self.with_context(no_reset_password=True)).create(vals)

        return user
```